# PHP XML inserting element after (or before) another element

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have a previously generated XML like this:

```
<newsletter>

    <header>
        </magazine>
        </image>
        <strap/>
    </header>

    <intro>
        <date/>
        <text/>
        </edimg>
    </intro>

    <shop>
        <heading/>
        <article/>
        <title/>
        <img/>
        <link/>
        <excerpt/>
    </shop>

    <sidebar>
        <cover/>
        <cover_link/>
        <text/>
        <advert>
        <link/>
        <image/>
        </advert>
    </sidebar>

</newsletter>
```

I need to be able to insert an element in between  the `<intro>` and the `<shop>` elements

this:

```
$section = $dom->documentElement->appendChild($dom->createElement('section'));
```

will just create the element within `<newsletter>` .

I assumed this would be fairly simple , but cannot seem to find a solution .

Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for the `insertBefore` method I presume, just search for the `shop` element and insert before that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try this; I didn't test it, but the solution comes from using insertBefore instead of appendChild.

```
$shop = $dom->getElementsByTagName("shop")->item(0);
$section = $dom->documentElement->insertBefore($dom->createElement('section'),$shop);
```

Comment: Thanks to Rik I came to the above solution with getElementsByTagName . Thanks to everyone else for the lightning quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the `<shop>` node and use

- [`DOMNode::insertBefore` — Adds a new child before a reference node](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php)

instead of appending to the `documentElement`.

You can do that from the `DOMDocument` as well when passing in the shop node as second argument. Personally, I find it easier to just do that from the shop node because you have to fetch it anyway:

```
$shopNode->insertBefore($newNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$section = $dom->documentElement->insertBefore(
    $dom->createElement('section'), 
    $shop)
);
```

where `$shop` points to the `<shop>` element.