# I need to customize xml tags

Tags: php, xml

I need to make some changes to the xml tags I use. I need to collect some of these tags in other tags.
**For example:**

```
<image> image_url </image>
the tags
<Images>
    <Image> image_url <image>
</Images>
```

must be

I may also need to use some tags below or above the existing tag

**For example:**

```
<productname> pr_name </productname>
<newproductname> pr_name </newproductname>
```

**Test xml output:**

```
<Root>
  <Products>
    <Product>
        <productname> pr_name </productname>
        <price> pr_price </price>
        <sku> pr_sku </sku>
        <Image> image_url <image>
    <Product>
  </Products>
</Root>
```

**I want it this way :)**

```
<Root>
  <Products>
    <Product>
        <newproductname> pr_name </newproductname>

        <productname> pr_name </productname>
        <price> pr_price </price>
        <sku> pr_sku </sku>
        <Images>
            <Image> image_url <image>
        </Images>

        <newsku> pr_newsku </newsku>
    <Product>
  </Products>
</Root>
```

How do I make changes to this **structure** that I use like.

```
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->load('test.xml');
$xml_string = $xml->saveXML();
echo $xml_string;
```

Comment: PD https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723747/php-xml-inserting-element-after-or-before-another-element

Comment: Thanks... i don't think it's the same thing

Comment: I think the link @splash58 gave you gives sufficient guidance to accomplish this task - after all, thus far all you have done is explain what you want but not actually attempted anything yourself.

Comment: @RamRaider I tried them actually but couldn't group the labels. That's my problem.

Comment: $element = $xml->createElement('images');
$element->appendChild($xml->documentElement);
$xml->appendChild($element);

Comment: I tried like that, but it only came out at the beginning and at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the sample XML below, which is based upon that cited in the question but expanded slightly and corrected the badly formed XML as seen above, you can easily achieve the desired structure with careful use of `DOMXPath` and `insertBefore` - with a little twist on the latter to actually perform `insertAfter`

```
$xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Root>
            <Products>
                <Product>
                    <productname> pr_name 1</productname>
                    <price> pr_price 1</price>
                    <sku> pr_sku 1</sku>
                    <Image> image_url 1.1</Image>
                    <Image> image_url 1.2</Image>
                </Product>
                <Product>
                    <productname> pr_name 2</productname>
                    <price> pr_price 2</price>
                    <sku> pr_sku 2</sku>
                    <Image> image_url 2</Image>
                </Product>

                <Product>
                    <productname> pr_name 3</productname>
                    <price> pr_price 3</price>
                    <sku> pr_sku 3</sku>
                    <Image> image_url 3.1</Image>
                    <Image> image_url 3.2</Image>
                    <Image> image_url 3.3</Image>
                </Product>

                <Product>
                    <productname> pr_name 4</productname>
                    <price> pr_price 4</price>
                    <sku> pr_sku 4</sku>
                </Product>
            </Products>
        </Root>';



$dom=new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
$dom->formatOutput=true;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace=false;
$dom->loadXML( $xml );
$errors = libxml_get_errors();
libxml_clear_errors();




$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query( '//Products/Product' );
if( $col->length > 0 ){

    foreach( $col as $node ){

        /* Get the `productname` and create a new element before with same value */
        $productname=$xp->query( 'productname', $node )->item(0);
        $newproductname=$dom->createElement( 'newproductname', $productname->textContent );
        $node->insertBefore( $newproductname, $productname );

        /* Find all the Image tags within parent */
        $ref=$xp->query( 'Image', $node );

        /* determine reference node to use for `insertBefore` */
        if( $ref && $ref->length > 0 )$refNode=$ref->item(0);
        else $refNode=$node->lastChild;

        /* create a new `Images` node */
        $oImages=$dom->createElement('Images');
        $node->insertBefore( $oImages, $refNode );

        /* using previously discovered `Image` nodes, add to the new `Images` element */
        foreach( $ref as $img )$oImages->appendChild( $img );
    }
}

/* for demo display */
printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( htmlentities( $dom->saveXML() ), true ) );

/* For real output */
#header( 'Content-Type: application/xml' );
#exit( $dom->saveXML() );
```

The output from the debug print ( `printf` above ) is as follow and follows, I believe, the desired output format - apart from new, unmentioned `newsku` tag which you show above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
  <Products>
    <Product>
      <newproductname> pr_name 1</newproductname>
      <productname> pr_name 1</productname>
      <price> pr_price 1</price>
      <sku> pr_sku 1</sku>
      <Images>
        <Image> image_url 1.1</Image>
        <Image> image_url 1.2</Image>
      </Images>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <newproductname> pr_name 2</newproductname>
      <productname> pr_name 2</productname>
      <price> pr_price 2</price>
      <sku> pr_sku 2</sku>
      <Images>
        <Image> image_url 2</Image>
      </Images>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <newproductname> pr_name 3</newproductname>
      <productname> pr_name 3</productname>
      <price> pr_price 3</price>
      <sku> pr_sku 3</sku>
      <Images>
        <Image> image_url 3.1</Image>
        <Image> image_url 3.2</Image>
        <Image> image_url 3.3</Image>
      </Images>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <newproductname> pr_name 4</newproductname>
      <productname> pr_name 4</productname>
      <price> pr_price 4</price>
      <Images/>
      <sku> pr_sku 4</sku>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</Root>
```

Comment: Man, you're great! Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm changing the names of some tags when capturing the xml file. For example: image1 tag image is doing so I'm pressing the screen. Since the code you provided reads the contents of the original xml file, I cannot read the fields I changed and therefore cannot group image fields.

Comment: The code I've modified: : http://prntscr.com/pdge6j

Output: http://prntscr.com/pdgf4p